# How to draw a Block Diagram like this

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw this block diagram

[image: Block diagram]

and I'm not finding any similar diagram or any tutorial to know how to do it. Could anybody help me?

I have done this:

```
%Flowcharting techniques for easy maintenance
%Author: Brent Longborough
\documentclass[x11names]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
\begin{document}
 \pgfdeclarelayer{marx}
 \pgfsetlayers{main,marx}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
>=triangle 60,              % Nice arrows; your taste may be different
start chain=going below,    % General flow is top-to-bottom
node distance=6mm and 60mm, % Global setup of box spacing
every join/.style={norm},   % Default linetype for connecting boxes
]

\tikzset{
base/.style={draw, on chain, on grid, align=center, minimum height=5ex},
base2/.style={draw, on chain, on grid, align=center, minimum height=7ex},
pric/.style={base2, rectangle, text width=6em},
proc/.style={base, rectangle, text width=18em},
pruc/.style={base, circle, text width=3em},
test/.style={base, diamond, aspect=1.5, text width=8em},
term/.style={proc, rounded corners},

coord/.style={coordinate, on chain, on grid, node distance=6mm and 25mm},
nmark/.style={draw, cyan, circle, font={\sffamily\bfseries}},

norm/.style={->, draw, lcnorm},
norm/.style={->, draw, lcnorm},
free/.style={->, draw, lcfree},
cong/.style={->, draw, lccong},
it/.style={font={\small\itshape}}
 }

\node [pruc, join] (p0) {};

\node [term, join]      {};
\node [term, join]      {};
\node [term, join] (t0)     {};
\node [pric] (t1)      {};
\node [test] (t2) {};


 \node [term, join=by free] {};
  \node [pruc, join] (p0) {};
 \draw [<-,lcnorm] (t0) -- (t1);
 \draw [<-,lcnorm] (t1) -- (t2);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 % =================================================
 \end{document}
```

[image]

But I don't know how to draw the intermediate boxes that are locates on the left and on the right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239462/drawing-a-block-diagram-with-tikz?rq=1

Comment: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/labs-schema/, http://texample.net/tikz/examples/android/, http://texample.net/tikz/examples/flexible-flow-chart/

Comment: Dive into: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=flow+chart

Comment: welcome to tex.se! here is not service "do-it-for-me", so, please show us, what you try so far. you can find a lot of flowchart examples here on site on by googling, which can serve as starting point. a tp: probably it would be more simple to draw it from bottom to top ...

Comment: I'm sorry. I'have used the example from Brent Longborough but I have problems to draw the intermediate boxes that are located on the left and right.

Answer (score 4):

is it enough close to what you like to draw?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, shapes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}},
        }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
node distance = 4mm and -4mm,   % Global setup of box spacing
  start chain = going above,    % General flow is top-to-bottom
%
   LA/.style = {Stealth-},
 base/.style = {draw,
                minimum size=3ex, inner sep=2mm, align=center,
                on chain, join=by LA},
 sbox/.style = {base, rectangle, text width=6em},
 wbox/.style = {base, rectangle, text width=18em},
 term/.style = {sbox, rectangle, rounded corners},
 test/.style = {base, diamond, aspect=1.5,
                inner xsep=0mm, text width=8em},
                        ]
% from bottom to top
\node (n1)  [term]          {};
\node (n2)  [wbox]          {};
\node (n3)  [test]          {};
\node (n4)  [sbox, suppress join,
             minimum height=5ex]                        {};
% left column
\node (n5a) [sbox, suppress join, above  left=of n4]    {};
\node (n6a) [sbox]          {};
\node (n7a) [sbox]          {};
% right column
\node (n5b) [sbox, suppress join, above right=of n4]    {};
\node (n6b) [sbox]          {};
\node (n7b) [sbox]          {};
% top column
\node (n8)  [wbox, suppress join, above=of n7a.north -| n4]   {};
\node (n9)  [wbox]          {};
\node (n10) [wbox]          {};
\node (n11) [term]          {};
%
\draw[LA]   (n4) edge (n3)
            (n8) edge (n4);
\draw[LA]   (n7a) edge (n7a |- n8.south)  (n3) -| (n5a);
\draw[LA]   (n7b) edge (n7b |- n8.south)  (n3) -| (n5b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what you will retouch? my answer? :-)

Comment: The ratio width/height of the rectangles ;)

Comment: i consider width of nodes, but heights i estimate to be to big, so i reduce it (to obtain smaller image). anyway, i get impression, that answer help you, so you can accept it :)

Comment: but you still not accept answer :). newer mind, i can leave without your acceptance ...